# camera app is not starting in phone

Tags: android

I am making camera app but when i m running it it shows unfortunately app has stopped.In the code it shows no error but still its not working so help me with it.

the below code is the main code of the app and contains the captured image saving file

```
package com.example.cam;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CamTestActivity extends Activity  {
    private static final String TAG = "CamTestActivity";
    Preview preview;
    Button buttonClick;
    Camera camera;
    Activity act;
    Context ctx;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ctx = this;
        act = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        preview = new Preview(this, (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView));
        preview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout)).addView(preview);
        preview.setKeepScreenOn(true);

        preview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
            }
        });

        Toast.makeText(ctx,getString(R.string.take_photo_help), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);

                buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        preview.mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
                        camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
                    }
                });

                buttonClick.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                        camera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback(){
                            @Override
                            public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
                                camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
                            }
                        });
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        int numCams = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        if(numCams > 0){
            try{
                camera = Camera.open(0);
                camera.startPreview();
                preview.setCamera(camera);
            } catch (RuntimeException ex){
                Toast.makeText(ctx, getString(R.string.camera_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if(camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            preview.setCamera(null);
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void resetCam() {
        camera.startPreview();
        preview.setCamera(camera);
    }

    private void refreshGallery(File file) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
        sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
                         Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
        }
    };

    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                         Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
        }
    };

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            new SaveImageTask().execute(data);
            resetCam();
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
        }
    };

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... data) {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;

            // Write to SD Card
            try {
                File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/camtest");
                dir.mkdirs();               

                String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
                File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);

                outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                outStream.write(data[0]);
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();

                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length + " to " + outFile.getAbsolutePath());

                refreshGallery(outFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

hear the preview code and contains preview after capturing the photo

```
    package com.example.cam;

/*
 * @author Jose Davis Nidhin
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private final String TAG = "Preview";

    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Size mPreviewSize;
    List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    Camera mCamera;

    Preview(Context context, SurfaceView sv) {
        super(context);

        mSurfaceView = sv;
        addView(mSurfaceView);

        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        mCamera = camera;
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            requestLayout();

            // get Camera parameters
            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

            List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
            if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
                // set the focus mode
                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
                // set Camera parameters
                mCamera.setParameters(params);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // We purposely disregard child measurements because act as a
        // wrapper to a SurfaceView that centers the camera preview instead
        // of stretching it.
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        if (changed && getChildCount() > 0) {
            final View child = getChildAt(0);

            final int width = r - l;
            final int height = b - t;

            int previewWidth = width;
            int previewHeight = height;
            if (mPreviewSize != null) {
                previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
                previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
            }

            // Center the child SurfaceView within the parent.
            if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth) {
                final int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
                child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0,
                        (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
            } else {
                final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
                child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2,
                        width, (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
            }
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
    }


    private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        if(mCamera != null) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            requestLayout();

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    }

}
```

this is the crash log

```
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
D/AccessibilityManager: getInstance() new sInstance = android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager@4ed699a, context = com.example.cam.CamTestActivity@65f12cb, userId = 0
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.cam, PID: 3386
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cam/com.example.cam.CamTestActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2477)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5452)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
                   Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:326)
                      at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:3656)
                      at com.example.cam.CamTestActivity.onCreate(CamTestActivity.java:45)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2477) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5452) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3386 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

now please help me solving the problem

Comment: did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>` in manifest file

Comment: yes i have addedd all permissions

Comment: than share crash log with question

Comment: In which device/API version are you running your app ? @HusainSongadhwala

Comment: In API level 23

Comment: Look into my Answer , You have to check permission i.e Runtime permission for API 23 and above . @HusainSongadhwala

Answer (score 0):

Enable different permissions at a single time on app startup in android programmatically.

Here you need to add only CAMERA permission for above Marshmallow Devices, Add this code before Starting your Camera Screen

References :https://www.android-examples.com/request-check-multiple-runtime-permissions-android-marshmallow/

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

**MainActivity.java** Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
public static final int RequestPermissionCode = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(checkPermission()){

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "All Permissions Granted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else {

                requestPermission();
            }

        }
    });
}


private void requestPermission() {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]
            {
                    CAMERA,

            }, RequestPermissionCode);

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case RequestPermissionCode:

            if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                boolean CameraPermission = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;


                if (CameraPermission ) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }

            break;
    }
}

public boolean checkPermission() {

    int FirstPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), CAMERA);


    return FirstPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ;
}

}
```

Or, If you to check Manually without using this Code, *its just for check*   :
Go to Settings -> Apps -> Select Your App -> tap on permissions -> enable Camera Permission.

Answer (score 0):

In your `CamTestActivity`, move the line `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` so it appears before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`